# Using Information from Log File to Combat Spam

Tags: spam, referrer, malware, apache-log-files, blacklist

I'm dealing with a site (not Wordpress, nor any other CMS) that was previously hacked and at that time I had found a php file in the images directory that was being used to generate spam from the site.  Now I've watched the 404 errors climb back into the 2000+ range in webmaster tools.  People have told me not to worry about this, but a large number of 404 errors preceded the previous issue, and I had to go through the whole resubmission/reconsideration ordeal with Google.  At this point, running the site check on Sucuri's website shows this site is blacklisted, but only with them (Sucuri) at this point.

I can't track down any funny looking code or files on the server, and I've changed the FTP login information.  I do see viagra and cialis links in the log files, but don't know how to use this information to clean up the site or protect it better.  At one point, I was blocking specific URLs within my htaccess, but this doesn't seem to have an effect anymore.  The client is hesitant to switch hosts.  Any suggestions about how I can use what I am seeing in the logs to disassociate my site from the spammers?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it may be worth paying Sucuri to get them to log into your server and do a more complete check for malicious code or backdoors installed.  Their free check only finds malware that is actively attempting to infect visitors and reports blacklist status.  Before any other steps can be taken you need to make sure your site and server are indeed clean.

Once that has been resolved, you will want to analyze the 404 errors in the log to see if there is a common element that can be used to block via .htaccess methods if you want to do this yourself.  Alternately, services such as CloudFlare can help to block the bad links before getting to the server and thus registering the 404 error but CloudFlare does come with some other baggage that may affect your decision to use it.